# Black mold or termites?

Tags: mold, baseboard, termite

[image][image]
I’m not sure bout the bug or the mold looking stuff the board is dry and so was the wall behind it but it’s def dark enough there. Any thoughts would be great[image]

Comment: I'm no expert but to me that looks like neither. Can you give us more details on what you removed to expose this? Where? Was it wet? Smelly? Interior or exterior?

Comment: It’s the back of a baseboard of a house we just bought it didn’t look wet or really smell, maybe slightly musty but nothing strong. The only thing I saw that could result in moisture is the other side of that wall is the garage and close to the water heater however there is no indication of water damage there.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. That looks like a cockroach egg case to me (ah, college...). On the black spots, could you add a closeup with a ruler? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: It may be a mold but there are hundreds of types of molds that are “black”. Are you concerned the house is falling apart? A little more info in the question would be helpful. Will it wipe off is there any substance to it when wiped or just color.

Comment: That definitely looks like cockroach poop. More so since you said it was found behind the baseboard and what looks like an egg sac. Roaches like to live and hide in dark places where they won't be bothered, behind trim is the perfect place! Never really seen mold in tiny dots like that, the spores usually grow in bigger clumps.

Comment: The only reason I would think it’s mold is cuz it’s looks more fury and attached to the board I’ll see if I can get a better pic